# Optimize mysql query

Tags: mysql

Below query taking one sec to execute. I need to optimize following. I have 10 query in my page, so its takes more than 15 sec. loading the page. I need help to optimize the query.

```
SELECT p.mhSlug, p.cgSlug, p.CatDescription, p.cSlug, COUNT(DISTINCT(p.RootModelNumber)) AS prodCount 
FROM tbl_products AS p 
STRAIGHT_JOIN ModelPrice AS mp ON (mp.product_id = p.id AND mp.Available = 1) STRAIGHT_JOIN Brand_Data AS bd ON bd.pkID = p.pkBrand 
STRAIGHT_JOIN tbl_store_brands AS sb ON sb.categoryID = p.pkCategory AND sb.brandID = p.pkBrand 
LEFT JOIN tbl_filters AS f ON (f.SKU = p.SKU)
WHERE mhSlug = 'plumbing' AND p.cgSlug = 'bathroom-fixtures' AND mp.Available = 1
GROUP BY p.cSlug 
ORDER BY p.cSlug
```

**Here EXPLAIN:**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  p   ref     PRIMARY,pkBrand,cgslug,mhslug,pkCategory,CategoryrBrand,mhcgc,mhcg  cgslug  228     const   41164   Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  mp  ref     product_id,product_idAvail  product_id  9   ekidtv_uakc.p.id    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  bd  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY     4   ekidtv_uakc.p.pkBrand   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  sb  ref     brandID,categoryID,brandCat,CatBrand    brandCat    10  ekidtv_uakc.bd.pkID,ekidtv_uakc.p.pkCategory    1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  f   ref     SKU,SKUSortField    SKU     303     ekidtv_uakc.p.SKU   2   Using index
```

Please help any body. I have struggle last two days.

Any body able to help me. I did not any improvement.

Comment: Add indexes to columns

Comment: If you need help with query optimization then you must document the db structure (indexes, keys, etc...) and you must show us the explain plan. Without this information we can only guess... which is useless. As is, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: `STRAIGHT_JOIN` will force a read of the left table in the join before the right table. Is there any reason why you're forcing a bypass of the optimizer and use the proprietary `STRAIGHT_JOIN` over `JOIN` ?

Comment: What is tbl_filters JOINed for? You don't seem to use any of its columns for the SELECT or the WHERE or the GROUP BY. That is a LEFT JOIN... costly, especially if not used.

Comment: Thanks for all @frazz I have add the EXPLAIN of the query. Could you please help for me.

Comment: Please any body help for Optimize the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create or review the indexes on your tables. See [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) documentation for mysql.
I dont see anything wrong on your query.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.